# Session Variable not accessible when opening website on other device [php code]

Tags: php

I have local host website. Connected two devices to a hotspot and accessing the website using the ip of the server. All the pages open properly but the session variable is not recognised as "Undefined Index" error throws up.

While when I access the same  on the localhost I donot face this issue.

I have used session_start() in all the files.

Have the code snipped of Login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

?>
<html>
<head><title>LOGIN</title></head>
<body>
<form action= "Dashboard.php" method = "POST">

        <br/>Name: <input type = "text" name = "name">
        <br/>Password: <input type = "password" name = "password">
        <br/><input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "submit"> or <a href="Register.php">Register</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>




<?php   

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","nets") or die("Couldn't connect to database");

    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name = '$name' and Password='$password'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($count == 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $name;
        echo "Login Successful";
    }else{
        echo "Invalid Login Credentials";
    }
}
?>
```

After login Dashboard.php

```
    <?php
session_start();

?>
<html>
<head><title>Dashboard</title></head>
<body>
<form action= "" method = "POST">
        <?php echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['username'].".<br>";        
        ?>
        <br/>Sex: <select name="sex"> <option value ="Male">Male</option> <option value = "Female">Female</option></select>
        <br/>Age: <select name="years">
            <?php 
                for($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
                {
                echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                }
            ?> 
                 <option name="years"> </option>   
            </select> 
        <br/>Citizen: <select name="citizen"><option value="Singaporean">Singaporean</option><option value="International">International</option></select>

        <a href="Download.php">Click to Download!</a>

        <br/><input type="submit" name = "submit2" value = "Save Changes"> or<a href="Login.php">Logout</a> 


</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php   

if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){

    $name = $_SESSION['username'];

            $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","nets") or die("Couldn't connect to database");
            $query1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT Sex,Age,Citizen FROM users where Name = '$name'");
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query1))
            /* {
                echo "Details Entered in Database:".".<br>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "Name:".$_SESSION['username'].".<br>"; 
                echo "Sex:".$row[0].".<br>";
                echo "Age:".$row[1].".<br>";
                echo "Citizen:".$row[2].".<br>";
             }*/
             $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $years = $_POST['years'];
    $citizen = $_POST['citizen'];
             $query2 = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE users SET Sex = '$sex', Age='$years', Citizen='$citizen' WHERE Name = '$name'");
             echo "Saved changes";
}

?>
```

Please suggest

Comment: session value are communicated by HTTP cookies, which shares on same host name. IP and 'localhost' are different.

Comment: any suggestions how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has the action "Dashboard.php", so that script will handle the submission of your login form.

In other words, the logic inside the code block for the if statement `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` is probably not executed, so your session variable isn't set.

You can set the action to "Login.php" or leave it blank to let Login.php handle the login, then you can redirect to Dashboard.php if you desire and the session variable should be set.

Do mind that if you want to redirect using PHP, it must be done before the HTML. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what exactly is needed to be done as I see that the  code block for the if statement if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){ is executed.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in the statement, I changed it slightly.

On your Login.php you have a big if-statement at the bottom of your code which should handle the user login and set the session variable. Because the form action is "Dashboard.php", the results of the login form will be directly sent to Dashboard.php, without first going through that if-statement. So the action of your login form needs to be changed. If you leave it blank, the form will be handled by Login.php instead of Dashboard.php and so the that if-statement should work too.